# html2canvas image of google maps - polygon clipped by edges of map tiles

Tags: google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3, html2canvas

When saving a canvas created from a google map containing a polygon, the polygon is being clipped where the tile edges are - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BML6.jpg).
[image: Imgur]

Both the polygon and polylines are being clipped right across, this issue is not seen in the map, just when saving the image through html2canvas.

```
// Setup vars
var $this = $(this),
    $mapContainer = $('#area-map .gm-style div:first'),
    $input = $('input[name="map_image_data"]')

// Run HTML2Canvas to convert map to data image
html2canvas($mapContainer, {
    proxy : 'html2canvasproxy.php',
    useCORS : false,
    logging : true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        $input.val(dataURL);
    }
});
```

html2canvas logging output:

```
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images 
html2canvas: Preload: Done.
html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 2 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 3 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 4 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 5 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 6 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 7 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 8 / 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: start: images: 9 / 9 (failed: 0)
Finished loading images: # 9 (failed: 0)
html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj
```

I have been trying to move the polygon to another map pane but haven't had any luck.